# Resizable div in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to develop the layout as mentioned below in bootstrap.

```
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="content">
     <div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
     <div id="content">Content</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
```

The header should be navigation header.
The sidebar should be resizable div.On resizing the sidebar content width should be adjusted according to that.
The footer div is panel used to put the messages.

I have used the nav bar from bootstrap for displaying header.
I am unable find the resizable div.

Answer (score 3):

Add the CSS with following style :

```
  sidebar{
          resize: both;
          overflow: auto;
         }
```